# How to create an SWC file

Tags: apache-flex, flash, swc, compc

All I want is to take my AS3 source code files and compile them into a SWC file.

Upon inspection, the SWC files I generate end up with some kind of timeline or spite in them when I use the Flash IDE or that Flex SDK utility "compc", and it's irritating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash is timeline based; so everything in Flash uses a timeline.  They hide it very well in Flex, though, so it's not obvious under the hood.

To create a SWC file in Flex, you need to use the command line compiler, although it sounds like you've already done that, so I'm unclear what your issue is.

Comment: I just hate junk in files.  The SWC shouldn't need a timeline, but it has a SWF embedded in it, which obviously has a timeline.  It's such a hack.  So the short answer is that "random-number...Sprite" symbol in the SWC is necessary junk.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can build a "flex library project" in Flash builder. place your AS3 source code files in this project, it would automatic generate a swc file in which your AS3 Class;